# AppStore is showing manny langueges support, will infact I sppourt only English

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

At the AppStore, it looks as if my app supports multiple languages

[image]

At the Itunes-connect my app supports only English localized, I have no ether option to choose from..
I would still like the app to show at all AppStores worldwide, but to show I support only the English languege

ItunesConnent state:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your PROJECT > Info > Localizations. If Many language is showing, that means your app support those languages.

[image]

Comment: The results are the same as your screen shot, only english, yet at the app store there are manny more..